# How to run a .jar file, which contains OpenCV code and was created using ant, from command line?

Tags: java, opencv, ant, jar, noclassdeffounderror

I am trying to run a small java class from Ubuntu console, which contains OpenCV code like this :

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;

class SimpleSample {

    static{ System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME); }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to OpenCV " + Core.VERSION);
        Mat m = new Mat(5, 10, CvType.CV_8UC1, new Scalar(0));
        System.out.println("OpenCV Mat: " + m);
        Mat mr1 = m.row(1);
        mr1.setTo(new Scalar(1));
        Mat mc5 = m.col(5);
        mc5.setTo(new Scalar(5));
        System.out.println("OpenCV Mat data:\n" + m.dump());
    }
}
```

I built this using ant; the build.xml looks like this:-

```
<project name="SimpleSample" basedir="." default="rebuild-run">

    <property name="lib.dir"     value="/opencv-2.4.7/build/bin"/>
    <path id="classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
    </path>

    <property name="build.dir"   value="build"/>
    <property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes"/>
    <property name="jar.dir"     value="${build.dir}/jar"/>

    <property name="main-class"  value="${ant.project.name}"/>


    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
        <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" classpathref="classpath"/>
    </target>

    <target name="jar" depends="compile">
         <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
         <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
             <manifest>
                 <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
             </manifest>
         </jar>
    </target>

    <target name="run" depends="jar">
        <java fork="true" classname="${main-class}">
            <sysproperty key="java.library.path" path="/opencv-2.4.7/build/lib"/>
            <classpath>
                <path refid="classpath"/>
                <path location="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar"/>
            </classpath>
        </java>
    </target>

    <target name="rebuild" depends="clean,jar"/>

    <target name="rebuild-run" depends="clean,run"/>

</project>
```

When given the command "ant", the code produces following output:-

```
Buildfile: /opencv-2.4.7/samples/java/ant/build.xml

clean:
    [delete] Deleting directory /opencv-2.4.7/samples/java/ant/build

compile:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /opencv-2.4.7/samples/java/ant/build/classes
    [javac] Compiling 1 source file to /opencv-2.4.7/samples/java/ant/build/classes

jar:
    [mkdir] Created dir: /opencv-2.4.7/samples/java/ant/build/jar
    [jar] Building jar: /opencv-2.4.7/samples/java/ant/build/jar/SimpleSample.jar

run:
    [java] Welcome to OpenCV 2.4.7.0
    [java] OpenCV Mat: Mat [ 5*10*CV_8UC1, isCont=true, isSubmat=false, nativeObj=0x7fc23c1bbc90, dataAddr=0x7fc23c1bbd50 ]
    [java] OpenCV Mat data:
    [java] [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0;
    [java]   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1;
    [java]   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0;
    [java]   0, libdc1394 error: Failed to initialize libdc1394
    [java] 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0;
    [java]   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0]

rebuild-run:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 3 seconds
```

But when I try to run the .jar file that was generated in the previous step by ant, using command `java -jar SimpleSample.jar`, it gives the following error :-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/opencv/core/Core
    at SimpleSample.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.opencv.core.Core
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

**I intend to run the SimpleSample.jar file from command line itself, without any error. Can someone tell me what do I need to do to accomplish that?**

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by packaging the OpenCV library jar with the jar I built. In the **"jar"** target of the **build.xml**, I added a **"zipgroupfileset"** attributed like this :-

```
<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
    <jar destfile="/home/krozona/dev/programs/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/webapps/Krozona/WEB-INF/lib/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
        <zipgroupfileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
    </jar>
</target>
```

Comment: I get a `no main manifest attribute, in SimpleSample.jar` when i do this. Did you get something similar? and possible resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem being you have not specified your class path correctly, so probably your dependencies are not bundled appropriately.

You must change your **build.xml** file.
Add the following things to your **build.xml**

```
<path id="libraries.path">    
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
</path>

<target name="jar" depends="compile">
         <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
         <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}/${lib.dir}"/>
         <copy todir="${jar.dir}/${lib.dir}" flatten="true">
            <path refid="libraries.path"/>
         </copy>
         <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
             <manifest>
                 <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
                 <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${jar.dir}/${lib.dir}/YOUR_JARS"/>
             </manifest>
         </jar>
</target>
```

Hope this works.

Comment: What should I enter at the command line? Because after making changes as you said and running "java -jar SimpleSample.jar" on console, it gives the same error.

Comment: Have you specified all the jars used by your code in your build.xml classpath?

Comment: It uses only one, i.e., "opencv-247.jar" and yes, I have specified it like this: "<attribute name="Class-Path" value="${jar.dir}/${lib.dir}/opencv-247.jar"/>"

Comment: Running a jar with -jar does not involve any kind of classpath mechanism since the jar file is the classpath.

Alternatively use a shell alias to launch the jar or a small script file.