# Issue running .jar file compiled with OpenCV using ANT

Tags: java, opencv, ant, manifest, noclassdeffounderror

I'm having an issue trying to run a jar file which contains OpenCV code I've compiled and run through `ANT` on my ubuntu server. The code an steps I've followed are from here: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html

So i have a simple application as follows:

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;

class SimpleSample {

  static{ System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME); }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Welcome to OpenCV " + Core.VERSION);
    Mat m = new Mat(5, 10, CvType.CV_8UC1, new Scalar(0));
    System.out.println("OpenCV Mat: " + m);
    Mat mr1 = m.row(1);
    mr1.setTo(new Scalar(1));
    Mat mc5 = m.col(5);
    mc5.setTo(new Scalar(5));
    System.out.println("OpenCV Mat data:\n" + m.dump());
  }

}
```

And i have my `build.xml` which contains the following:

```
<project name="SimpleSample" basedir="." default="rebuild-run">

       <property name="src.dir"     value="src"/>

       <property name="lib.dir"     value="/var/opencv/opencv/build/modules/java/pure_test/.build/simplesample/lib"/>
       <path id="classpath">
           <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
       </path>

       <property name="build.dir"   value="build"/>
       <property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes"/>
       <property name="jar.dir"     value="${build.dir}/jar"/>

       <property name="main-class"  value="${ant.project.name}"/>


       <target name="clean">
           <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
       </target>

       <target name="compile">
           <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
           <javac includeantruntime="false" srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" classpathref="classpath"/>
       </target>

       <path id="libraries.path">    
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
            <include name="*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
       </path>

    <target name="jar" depends="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
        <jar destfile="/var/opencv/opencv/build/modules/java/pure_test/.build/simplesample/lib/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
            <manifest>
             <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
         </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>

       <target name="run" depends="jar">
           <java fork="true" classname="${main-class}">
               <sysproperty key="java.library.path" path="/var/opencv/opencv/build/lib"/>
               <classpath>
                   <path refid="classpath"/>
                   <path location="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar"/>
               </classpath>
           </java>
       </target>

       <target name="rebuild" depends="clean,jar"/>

       <target name="rebuild-run" depends="clean,run"/>

   </project>
```

Now when i compile and run the above using `ANT` i get the correct response and from the files execution:

[image]

However When i attempt to run the jar file using `java -jar SimpleSample.jar` i receive a number of errors. Currently i get this `no main manifest attribute, in SimpleSample.jar` even though i do have a manifest attribute associated with the jar..

On other occasions I've gotten errors such as this, but i have been playing around with the `build.xml` file:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     org/opencv/core/Core
at SimpleSample.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.opencv.core.Core
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 1 more
```

I've looked at some question already to do with this issue on SO, such as [How to run a .jar file, which contains OpenCV code and was created using ant, from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20491856/how-to-run-a-jar-file-which-contains-opencv-code-and-was-created-using-ant-fr) which is basically the same problem i am having, but any solution i have tried has not worked.

Comment: can you post the content of the MANIFEST.MF file?

Comment: No such file exists I'm afraid. The jar application is compiled via `ANT` and i don't see anything resembling it in my directory.

Comment: i mean inside your SimpleSample.jar file ?

Comment: I don't entirely understand what you mean, is there a way i can decompile the .jar file to get this?

Comment: you could use winzip or any compression software to look at content inside in the jar file

Comment: Ok, just did it there, all that's contained in the file is the following: `Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.9.3
Created-By: 1.7.0_75-b13 (Oracle Corporation)

`